# Multiple Selections when using IF in order to delete at the end

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following two columns (simplified)

```
Bond   BMW
Equity Amazon
Bond   Netflix
Bond   Uber
Equity Google
```

I want a code that basically goes through the first column and deletes the row if it is an `Equity`.

My idea (in terms of the for-loop):

```
for i = 1 to 5
if ws.Cells(i,1).Value = "Bond" Then
Else 
ws.Rows(i).Select
End If 
Next i
Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

The problem that I have noticed is that only the last cell to be selected is deleted. I would have thought that all the cells I selected in the loop will be selected. Is there a specific way to select multiple. (`Union` would not work in this case, as it the list will be dynamic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when deleting rows, you would start at the bottom and work your way up.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, x

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(x, "A").Value = "Equity" Then

            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```